# Will lock prevent changes done via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, locking

Assume a class `SomeClass` with `private static` field like this. The access to this field is synchronized using `lock`.

```
private static SomeClass _instance
private static object _sync = new object();

public static SomeClass Instance 
{
    get 
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = Create();
            }
            return _instance;   
        }
    }
}
```

When another code from different thread will try to set the value of this variable to e.g. `null` using *reflection*, will the `lock` prevent this and let the reflection call wait until the lock was released?

E.g. something like this:

```
Type type = typeof(SomeClass);
string fieldName = "_instance";
object value = null;
FieldInfo field = type.GetField(fieldName, true);
field.SetValue(null, value);
```

Comment: the answer here is simply: *no*

Comment: this is a social-engineering problem - catch bad behavior in code reviews.

Comment: I think this question at least deserves an answer elaborating on the "why?", the technical, CLR-related reason. Documentation only says, "avoid using the following as *lock objects*: Type instances, as those might be obtained by the `typeof` operator **or reflection**" and that's not what OP does.

Comment: `lock` is *collaborative*. All code accessing the same protected resources has to be *written* to follow whatever locking rules you're trying to establish. If someone else writes code that accesses the protected resource(s) but doesn't follow your locking convention, nothing prevents that. How did you imagine that anything else would know, specifically, that `_sync` and `_instance` are related?

Comment: Basically, if your concern is some other piece of code accessing your protected resource via reflection, *don't let that other piece of code run inside you process under `FullTrust`*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I did not imagine it. The question is based on code which I already have at work. There are unit tests which in set up method manipulate private field via reflection setting the value to null. The tests when executed solo run green, but when all the tests in the project are executed, then  some tests fail because of mysterious null ref. exception. I spend relatively long time to find out the possible source of the null reference. So now I am sure that lock can't protect the reflection calls like it protects normal calls. Thanks guys for explanation and your comments.

Comment: @dee - it's got nothing to do with reflection. If you write another method in this class that accesses the same resource and fails to use the same lock object, that would also compile and run fine and race the same issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, lock will not prevent any access that does not go through locking the same resource. Since reflection will not go through `lock`, you will get race conditions. 
Here is (slightly different from your code but nontheless doing same thing) what I mean→

```
void SetOne(){
    lock (_sync){
         critical_element = SOME_VALUE;
     }
}

void SetTwo(){
   critical_element = SOME_ANOTHER_VALUE;
}
```

Above definitely has race conditions.

Here is my understanding behind the OP's question. I think OP wants to use `Singleton` pattern and here is a very nice and thread safe implementation. You do not need to deal with locks either. However, some bad users might still set the backing field using reflection.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton(){}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understood that the lock is effective only for calls which go through the normal access, but with reflection there the value is changed directly. That was my question, I was not sure, how the locking works. The singleton with Lazy of T is cool, thanks as well.